# Cómo mostrar los datos usando desde una ruta con laravel, usando js y json

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, api

Estoy realizando un calendario en la que agregue y visualice las actividades, pero se me ha complicado hacer que se visualicen los datos que subo. Para ello estoy usando laravel con la ruta de api, y obtengo su valor en un js. Cuando le doy `console.log()` se visualizan los datos, pero al hacerle llamado para que se muestren en la página no se llegan a visualizar.

Aquí dejo mi código

```
let events = []

$.get('api/calendario/obtenerDatos', function (data){
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('descripcion'+`${element.id}`)
        events.push({
            id: element.id,
            url: element.eventoURL,
            title: element.titulo,
            start: element.fechaInicio,
            end: element.fechaFinal,
            allDay: false,
            extendedProps: {
            calendar: 'personal'
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Como se puede observar en las siguientes imágenes, se puede visualizar en el terminal los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio cuando coloco el siguiente código, sí se llega a visualizar la actividad.

```
events.push({
    id: 0,
    url: '',
    title: 'Design Review',
    start: date,
    end: nextDay,
    allDay: false,
    extendedProps: {
      calendar: 'personal'
    }
})
```

Les coloco la imagen de cómo se visualiza este pequeño código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si coloco solo el primer código donde traigo los datos, no se visualiza nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No tendrá que ver con que al momento de pintar todavía no llegaron los datos de la llamada ajax? Como y cuando lo pintas a eso?

Comment: Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta. También, aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/607198/edit) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.